# What is the format of the Session Storage used in Chromium?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, session, html5

When websites make use of the HTML5 webstorage, Chromium stores the data of Local storage and Session storage in different directories. In my case (Ubuntu 16.04) that is `~/.config/chromium/Default/Local Storage` and `~/.config/chromium/Default/Session Storage`.

Local storage data is stored in SQLite databases that can be inspected with tools like `DB Browser for SQLite`. Chromium creates on database file per domain:

```
user@desktop-10:~/.config/chromium/Default/Local Storage$ ls -l
total 18
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016 4096 Mar  7 14:15 https_hangouts.google.com_0.localstorage
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016    0 Mar  7 14:15 https_hangouts.google.com_0.localstorage-journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016 3072 Mar  7 14:15 https_notifications.google.com_0.localstorage
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016    0 Mar  7 14:15 https_notifications.google.com_0.localstorage-journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016 3072 Mar  7 14:28 https_support.google.com_0.localstorage
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016    0 Mar  7 14:28 https_support.google.com_0.localstorage-journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016 3072 Mar  7 13:50 https_www.youtube.com_0.localstorage
-rw-r--r-- 1 user students2016    0 Mar  7 13:50 https_www.youtube.com_0.localstorage-journal
```

However, Session Storage is stored in a different way:

```
user@desktop-10:~/.config/chromium/Default/Session Storage$ ls -l
total 128
-rw------- 1 user students2016 33337 Mar  7 14:15 000005.ldb
-rw------- 1 user students2016 32946 Mar  7 14:28 000007.ldb
-rw------- 1 user students2016 34137 Mar  7 14:41 000009.ldb
-rw------- 1 user students2016  2148 Mar  7 15:06 000009.log
-rw------- 1 user students2016    16 Mar  7 13:50 CURRENT
-rw------- 1 user students2016     0 Mar  7 13:50 LOCK
-rw------- 1 user students2016   284 Mar  7 14:44 LOG
-rw------- 1 user students2016   284 Mar  7 14:43 LOG.old
-rw------- 1 user students2016   215 Mar  7 14:41 MANIFEST-000001
```

Does anyone know in what format the session data is stored and which tool I can use to inspect its content?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this too. I have done a clean installation of Linux and want to move my saved tabs and passwords to the new computer.  I copied and pasted the entire /home/ directory and got absolutely nothing on the new computer. It didn't even reinstall Chromium. Google sync doesn't work in Chromium. All I'm finding is tedious, labor-intensive non-solutions like "just copy and paste each individual URL from each of 400+ individual tabs, and put them in a text file on a thumbdrive, bro" and "write down all your passwords on a post-it note, bro."  Obviously that's unacceptable.  The session information is persistent. The browser reopens all the tabs when I reopen the browser on the old computer.  I just want to know where the files are that I have to move over.  That's all.  Does anyone have any answers other than "RTFM, bro?" I already copied over the entire /home/ directory and all the subdirectories and obviously it's not there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1152638)